# minify javascript file at runtime in .net Web forms

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I was at a microsoft meeting 6 months ago and I remember a speaker demonstrating in 
Visualstudio 2012 a way to minify your JavaScript code  easily at run time.

eg: you can see the full javascript file in the project and you publish the full file but when you run the page that uses it and view the javascript with fire bug you see the minified version.

He did something to the way he added it in the head. Do you know what I am talking about and can you point me in the right direction?

Is it possible with a web forms project page?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614441/runtime-bundling-and-minifying-in-mvc-4

Comment: Bundle? Web Essentials? Web Workbench?

Comment: solutions already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338570/minifying-and-combining-files-in-net    and may be you can check this project as well http://xpedite.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are refering to what Microsoft calls bundling and minification. You can find a detailed description here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Thanks, can you do it with a webforms project or only mvc

Comment: @Hello-World It is an ASP.NET 4 feature so you can also use it in WebForms. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx